# Google Sheets Copy Down Issue

Tags: google-sheets, spreadsheet, google-sheets-api

I have a google form that my students fill out daily. All form responses feed into one workbook. From the workbook, I have a spreadsheet for "Clean" data. Which is just the information from the responses sheet needed to graph progress. The formula I am using in A2 is: ='Form Responses 1'!N2
Nothing too complicated right?

However, each day that I want to show the kids their progress on the charts, I have to select the last two entries in the Clean Data worksheet and copydown the formulas in order for the new data to appear. Apparently, every time there is a new form submission, google sheets changes the cell address in the formulas. Is there any way around this?

Comment: please give a proper example and a screenshot of what you want, or several screenshots of your sheets, and show us what happens daily and what you expect from excel. thanks

Comment: It is kind of difficult to visualize the sheet, sample data and how it relates to graph. Can you post screenshot with sample data?

Comment: Not sure what it looks like is happening, but to fix a reference from changing you can use a $ in front of the cell coordinates, ='Form Responses 1'!$N$2.  That changes it from a relative reference to an absolute reference.

Comment: The copying down can be avoided by using arrayformulas. As has been said, some sample data to work with would be great.

Comment: You could also use a [Query](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093343?hl=en)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As JPV commented, the "pushing down of formulae" by form submissions may be counteracted by using an array formula (in row 2):

`=ArrayFormula('Form Responses 1'!N2:N)`

And as Akshin commented, if you were in fact bringing over a couple of columns for graphing purposes, you can do it all in one with QUERY. For example:

`=QUERY('Form Responses 1'!A:N,"select A, N",1)`

Comment: Perfect - The array worked great, as did the query method for graphing. Sorry for the lack of sample data, I tried making a copy and then sanitizing all of the confidential data, but it took me longer to do it than it took you to provide an answer. :)